# The object path '_reference().search()' isn't working when using the object across multiple "context.sync"

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js

I'm performing the search operation on word document of office 365 using search API on range object. I get the searchResult item, but when i call the searchResultitem.select() method it throw the exception :

"The object path '_reference().search()' isn't working for what you're trying to do. If you're using the object across multiple "context.sync" calls and outside the sequential execution of a ".run" batch, please use the "context.trackedObjects.add()" and "context.trackedObjects.remove()" methods to manage the object's lifetime."

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The solution depends on what you're doing. You may want to post a simplified snippet of what you're doing.

Comment: That being said, I can guess as to what might be happening.  Please see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37290133/678505.