# Word Javascript API insert table throws InvalidArgument exception

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, word-addins, word-2016

I´m trying to insert a table in my word document, but every time I get a `InvalidArgument` exception in my console.

Here is my code:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
            var selectionRange = context.document.getSelection();
            var paragraph = selectionRange.insertParagraph("", Word.InsertLocation.before);

            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    var table = paragraph.insertTable(3, 4, Word.InsertLocation.before, [
                        ["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"],
                        ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"],
                        ["test5", "test6", "test7", "test8"]
                    ]);
                    table.styleBuiltIn = Word.Style.gridTable1Light;
                })
                .then(context.sync)
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
```

Is there anything I´m doing wrong?

Comment: See if the following thread helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912457/cant-seem-to-use-ranges-across-calls-to-word-runcontext-in-office-js

Comment: I would suggest you comment all lines of code and then uncomment them one by one to identify which line is causing the issue.

Comment: Did you mean to write "Before" instead of "Word.InsertLocation.before"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. insertTable is only supported in Word API Version 1.3, which is supported in Office 2019. I´m working with an Office 2016, which only works with 1.1.

Reference Link to microsoft docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets

Comment: For all who want to create a table inside word and have only Word API Version 1.1, you can use insertHtml to insert a html based table inside your document.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
var paragraph = selectionRange.insertParagraph("", Word.InsertLocation.before);

var table = paragraph.insertTable(3, 4, Word.InsertLocation.before, [
                        ["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"],
                        ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"],
                        ["test5", "test6", "test7", "test8"]
                    ]);
```

with

```
var paragraph = selectionRange.insertParagraph("", "Before");

var table = paragraph.insertTable(3, 4, "Before", [
                        ["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"],
                        ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"],
                        ["test5", "test6", "test7", "test8"]
                    ]);
```